# Constant expression required error in switch statement with strings

Tags: java, android, string, enums, switch-statement

I get a JSON response which roughly looks like this.

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      ....
    }
  ]
}
```

The `status` field can have two values: *success* or *fail*.

So in my code, I have the following enum.

```
private enum Status {
    SUCCESS("success", 0),
    FAIL("fail", 1);

    private String stringValue;
    private int intValue;
    private Status(String toString, int value) {
        stringValue = toString;
        intValue = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return stringValue;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is in a switch statement, I need to check for the status value and execute code in each condition.

```
String status = jsonObj.getString("status");

switch (status) {
    case Status.SUCCESS.toString():
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Response is successful!");
    case Status.FAIL.toString():
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Response failed :(");
    default:
        return;
}
```

But I get the **Constant expression required** error at each case.

I checked the value returned by `Status.SUCCESS.toString()` and `Status.FAIL.toString()` which indeed return strings.

Any idea why this error still occur?

Comment: Do not forget the `break`. `switch(Status.fromValue(status)) { case Success:`

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess you got that response because a Java switch statement is a basic language feature, and information is readily available via Google.

Comment: Why wouldn't  you simply write `case "success":` and `case "failure":`?

Comment: @DavidWallace: I suppose doing that would mean typing "success" in more than one place, breaking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: Yes, but the alternative is to use the `valueOf` method, and `switch` on an `Enum` then; which is problematic because of the exception that it throws if the `String` is wrong.

Comment: @Bathsheba Sorry, I didn't mean to change that AFTER you replied to it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`case` statements have to be compile-time evaluable.

Something like `Status.SUCCESS.toString()` doesn't satisfy that. A string *literal*, on the other hand, does.

The obvious fix is to use an an `if` block.

Comment: I though the same. using if-else will suffice

Comment: Thank you. That works! `if` statements are not the most elegant thing but well, what to do. Thanks again.

Comment: .....but why tho?