# How can I get ID from ViewBinding to use it with switch case statement?

Tags: java, android-studio

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.iv_camera:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case mBinding.ivCamera.getId():
            break;
    }
}
```

The first case works perfectly fine however, the second one throws an error that says ***Constant Expression Required*** . Am i forced to use R.id.something or can I continue with view binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `case` statements in java needs to be compile time constant. Since `mBinding.ivCamera.getId()` is not thus the error. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915793/constant-expression-required-error-in-switch-statement-with-strings) is already an answer in detail.